# When to add で after つ?

Tags: grammar

- 昨日のレースは抜きつ抜かれつで面白かったね。
- 旧友と再会し、差しつ差されつ朝まで楽しんだ。
- 世の中は持ちつ持たれつ、困った時はお互い様ですよ。
- 追いつ追われつで、どちらが勝つか予想がつかない。

Sometimes I find つ is followed by で, but I am not sure the purpose of this で. Could you tell me when it is compulsory to add/not to add で and  when it is optional?

Comment: It seems to me that you are misreading some other kana as being つ (tsu), probably て (te).

Comment: @Ben It's 「～つ～つ」 structure, such as in the common phrase「持ちつ持たれつ」"give-and-take" https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4428/9831

Answer (score 2):

When ～つ～つ means ～たり～たりし**ながら** ("while doing ~~ and ~~"), it's not followed by で. eg:

> 「旧友と再会し、差しつ差されつ朝まで楽しんだ。」

差しつ差されつ here means 酒をついだりつがれたりし**ながら**, and modifies the verb (phrase) 「(朝まで)楽しんだ」.

> 「風に吹き飛ばされた赤い帽子は木の葉のように浮きつ沈みつ川を流れて行った。」

浮きつ沈みつ here means 浮いたり沈んだりし**ながら**, and modifies the verb (phrase) 「(川を)流れて行った」.

---

～つ～つ can function like a noun, and can be followed by の, で, or する, etc. eg:

> 「マラソンの最後の500メートルで二人の選手は抜きつ抜かれつ**の**接戦になった。」

抜きつ抜かれつ here (≂抜いたり抜かれたり) functions as a noun, and it's followed by a の. It modifies the noun 接戦.

> 「昨日のレースは抜きつ抜かれつ**で**面白かったね。」
>   「追いつ追われつ**で**、どちらが勝つか予想がつかない。」

抜きつ抜かれつ(≂抜いたり抜かれたり), 追いつ追われつ(≂追ったり追われたり) are both followed by the particle で, and express the reason for the main verb (phrase) 面白かった and どちらが勝つか予想がつかない, respectively. I think you could also interpret the で as the continuative form of the copula だ, and split the sentences as: 「昨日のレースは抜きつ抜かれつ**だった**。（それで/だから）面白かった。」「（レースは）追いつ追われつ**だ**。（それで/だから）どちらが勝つか予想がつかない」

> 「変な男の人がうちの前を行きつ戻りつ**している**。何をしているんだろう。」

行きつ戻りつ(≂行ったり戻ったり) here functions like a する-verb and is followed by している.

---

> 「世の中は持ちつ持たれつ、困った時はお互い様ですよ。」

You could think of the 世の中は持ちつ持たれつ part as a quote (引用) of a set phrase or a proverb ([諺]{ことわざ}). You could also think of this as two sentences, like 「世の中は持ちつ持たれつ。困った時はお互い様ですよ。」

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no strict rule when to add で after つ.

But I'd say that で after つ has a function of ending the flow of thought.

Ex. "昨日のレースは抜きつ抜かれつで" → The detail of レース would end, now other thing (speaker's impression or whatever) would continue. （Ex. 昨日のレースは抜きつ抜かれつで、白熱した）

"昨日のレースは抜きつ抜かれつ" → The detail of レース could continue. (Ex. 昨日のレースは抜きつ抜かれつ、Aが勝つと思ったらBが勝っていいレースだった )

I repeat, there is no strict rule, just a matter of nuance.